# Was he a Nazi in The Good Liar?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-good-liar

In the movie The Good Liar, we are shown that Hans took on the identity of Roy and escaped to England. But it appears Hans was stationed to hunt Nazis, and may not have been one himself.

In the end Lili says that she has a piece of hair of Hans which would prove that Roy is actually Hans. Roy looks perturbed at this information.

So, was Hans a Nazi?

Edit: I get that the film is about Lili's revenge for what Hans did to her. I'm asking about a specific sub-plot. Was Hans a Nazi or not? Steven insinuates he is, but Hans(Roy) claims he is not. Do the authorities consider Hans Taub to be a Nazi? If so, where in the film do we know this from?

Comment: @BCdotWEB Perhaps the question is not clear. Hans took on Roy's identity. That's quite clear. Was Hans a Nazi or not? That's all I'm looking for. Wikipedia is a very surface level article that doesn't have the answer I'm looking for.

Comment: I get your question - I believe he was a Nazi but has done a good job of covering it. But I can't remember any specific proof in the film.

Comment: @John - thanks. Wasn't he hunting a Nazi down with the real Roy, a British official, back in Berlin?

Comment: Judging from a transcript I've just read, it seems to me you're focusing on a minor, rather irrelevant detail that is already solved in the movie. Hans was conscripted into the German army and served on multiple fronts, so technically he might have been a Nazi. But there is no evidence he was even part of any atrocities; he was simply a soldier, as the dialogue clearly states.

Comment: @BCdotWEB "_it seems to me you're focusing on a minor_" - sure, yes. "_rather irrelevant detail_" - let me be the judge of that, I'm the OP here. If it's part of the film, it's relevant. "_that is already solved in the movie_" - no it's not. Your own comment makes that clear - "_he might have been a Nazi. But there is no evidence_".

Comment: Why not quote the whole sentence? As for "If it's part of the film, it's relevant" this site has a close reason that is "irrelevant detail". FYI the word "Nazi" is used three times in the movie, not exactly a sign of it being a major theme.

Comment: @BCdotWEB - not cool man. If it's irrelevant to you, you can simply ignore the question. If the question is unclear, that's a different matter.

Comment: @John It has nothing to do with it being irrelevant to me, it is irrelevant in the context of the movie. Plus: this question is answered in the movie.

Comment: @BCdotWEB I thought the whole point of this site was for "any" question related to films to be answered even if it is not the major portion of the movie. There are endless questions and rants on the site about some fringe element of Tenet. Which is fine, that's the point of the site. I just checked there is no close reason called irrelevant detail. Perhaps I'm not looking right .. but IMO there should be no such close reason. Close comments I'm seeing selected is that there are more questions than one here and that this needs to be split into two questions.

Comment: @John ["Unimportant trivia that does not add to the understanding or appreciation of the title."](https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). (Also, rants are off-topic as well.)

Comment: @BCdotWEB - This most definitely isn't trivia or a rant. It's a pretty valid question. Honestly, if you feel the question has an answer that the film provides, I'm not sure why that can't become the answer here. Isn't every question on the site answered in their respective movies?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In that scene in Berlin .. Steven accuses Roy not only to be Hans but also to be a Nazi. Roy accepts that he is indeed Hans but profusely denies the accusation that he was a Nazi. Going by what he says and existence of any records that connects Hans and the Nazi's it would be fair to say that Roy (or Hans) was not a Nazi.

However ... in the present day .. if Roy is exposed as Hans Taub to the authorities, it would be the case of an Identity Theft. Roy's con and crimes would all come forth and possibly lead to his arrest. He is a murderer after all.

If you're interested - In the book .. there is a much stronger indication that Hans Taub was a Nazi. And this is how he's able to get Lili's father killed in the past. Vincent's character is shown to be a Jew and that is the reason he switches sides and helps Steven and Lili.